# passing Date parameter to create date range query

Tags: java, jsp, postgresql, jdbc

Using the codes below I would like to ask how can I pass a "Date" parameter coming from a text field. I am planning to create a simple date range query using DAO and servlet. I can display all columns using this codes however I want to filter in using Date...

here's my code:

```
My Servlet




package source;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/**
 *
 * @author jaypee.martinez
 */
public class parseServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private parseDAO parseDAO;


    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost5432/mydb";
        String username = "postgres";
        String password = "secret";


        Database database = new Database(driver, url, username, password);
        this.parseDAO = new parseDAO(database);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


            try {

            List<parseBean> parse_array = parseDAO.results();

            request.setAttribute("parse_array", parse_array);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("results.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
            catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot retrieve areas", e);
        }
    }

}
```

and My DAO

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package source;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class parseDAO {

    private Database database;

    public parseDAO(Database database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public List<parseBean> results() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<parseBean> parse_array = new ArrayList<parseBean>();
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        try {
            connection = database.getConnection();
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from dateparse");


            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();


            while (resultSet.next()) {
                parseBean parsearray = new parseBean();
                parsearray.setDate(resultSet.getDate("date"));
                parsearray.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                parsearray.setAddress(resultSet.getString("address"));
                parse_array.add(parsearray);
            }
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        }

        return parse_array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to collect request parameters. Assuming that the input field has the name `date`.

```
String dateString = request.getParameter("date");
```

Use [`SimpleDateFormat#parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) to convert it to [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) using a specific pattern, depending on how the enduser was asked to enter the date.

```
Date date = null;

try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateString);
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    // Show error message to enduser about the wrong format and forward back to the JSP with the form.
    request.setAttribute("error", "Invalid format, please enter yyyy-MM-dd");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("search.jsp").forward(request, response);
    return;
}
```

Pass this as a method argument to your DAO method:

```
List<ParseBean> results = parseDAO.search(date);
```

You need to convert it to [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), so that you can use [`PreparedStatement#setDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) to set it on the SQL query:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM dateparse WHERE date = ?";
// ...
statement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

You can use `WHERE date > ?` to search for records newer than the given date, or `WHERE date < ?` to search for records older than the given date, or `WHERE date BETWEEN ? and ?` to search for records between the specified dates.

Comment: thanks again BalusC im really learning a lot from you... just want to clarify this:List<ParseBean> results = parseDAO.search(date);
should be placed in DAO class right?

Comment: No, just in the servlet as you have now. It makes no sense to let the DAO call itself :)

Comment: @BalusC: Isn't `date.getTime()` deprecated method ?

Comment: @Hardik: The answer is just in the javadoc.

Comment: hello i'm getting an error here: "public List<parseBean> results(Date date) throws SQLException {" --- reference to date is ambiguous. I'm not sure if i'm doing it right in DAO... I think everything is ok with the servelet... thanks in advance

Comment: You should not have `import java.sql.Date;`. You should use `new java.sql.Date(...)` exactly as in my answer. Otherwise Java get confused which one you mean, the `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` when you says `new Date(...)`. So: remove the `import java.sql.Date;` line, keep the `import java.util.Date;` line, and when you need to construct `java.sql.Date`, use `new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());`.

Comment: BALUSC You're the BEST!!! it is working now... you're more helpful than my counterpart hahahha

Comment: You're welcome :) Keep in mind that you should not be dealing with `java.sql.Date` inside the servlet class. Keep it inside the DAO class only. Also the model property should not be `java.sql.Date`, but only `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `doGet` you will get the value from request

```
String dateFromTxt = request.getParameter("DateFromTxtField");
```

Pass this to your dao's `results` method

then your `results` method may look like this :

```
public List<parseBean> results(String filterDate) throws SQLException {

   String query = "select * from dateparse where date = ? ";

   // get connection and prepare statement, also format the incoming date as per your database requirement then say you store this in variable myFormattedDate

   statement.setDate(1, myFormattedDate);

   // Execute query and fetch result.            

}
```