# How to reformat the time of Java Time class

Tags: java, sqlite, date, format, date-format

I searched topics about formatting time but these were all about Date class or DateTime. I am working with Time class. I created time as:

```
Time time = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone()) ;
time.setToNow();
String berkay = time.toString();
System.out.println(berkay);
```

When I execute it the output is :

> 20130417T070525GMT(3,106,0,0,1366182325)

actually date and time is correct (2013-04-17 07:05:25)

but I need to convert it into : 20130417070525 (My reason to do this is I will search database according to date so it is easier to compare times in that format)

How can I convert it?

Comment: will be much easier to compare if you store time as millis instead.

Comment: Read java.text.SimpleDateFormat javadoc.

Comment: Can we assume `java.sql.Time`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Does it matter please?

Comment: `1366182325` is TCP timestamp and for comparisons, sort etc, it is better to use that format instead of your own format

Comment: Yes. Without knowing what type of object `Time` is or what in extends from, it would virtually impossible to provide you with an accurate answer. For example, `java.sql.Time` extends from `Date`, meaning you could use the standard `DateFormat` classes

Comment: @smttp, you mean I can use 1366182325 to compare instead of compating real time and date ?

Comment: yes you can use it. 1366182325 is tcp timestamp number. it starts from 1 Jan 1970 00:00 GMT and increments 1 each second. http://www.timestampconvert.net/ shows what is the time in terms of that long number. I use that number because it is efficient both in time and space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Time time = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()) ;  
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss"); 
String date = df.format(time).toString(); 
System.out.println(date);
```

**EDIT**

But as  ***smttsp*** suggested its much more efficient to store it as timestamp

Comment: You can also just use a `Time` object in the call to `df.format()`.

Comment: I tried it.Time time = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone()) ;
           time.setToNow();
                      
           SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
           String date = df.format(time).toString();
           System.out.println(date);

but exception... :(

Comment: The first line : Time time = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()) ;  is working right on your computer ?

Comment: yes , i think there is a confusion i assumed the Time class is java.sql.Time is it right?

Comment: oouuchh, thanks mate. I was using import android.text.format.time. Your code worked super with java.sql.Time and that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

To convert java.util.Date into String you should consider java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

For using java.util.Date as a parameter of a database query you should pass the Date as is without converting it into any other format.

[passing Date parameter to create date range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690493/passing-date-parameter-to-create-date-range-query)
<- In the answer there is sample how to create such query.

Comment: you mean take the parameter as Date (not string etc..) so I can compare times in sql query right ?

Comment: if you have a column of date type - yes

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late but if you are working on time and you need to compare or sort, the best way is to use Unix timestamp. It starts from **1-Jan-1970 00:00:00** and increments 1 each second.

It is a long value(64 bit) which is quite efficient to use in both time and space. [Here](http://www.morecavalier.com/?whom=Apps/Unix%20timestamp%20converter) is the website for Unix timestamp conversion.

Also 20130417070525 is 14 char string(at least 15 byte, I guess) and 1366182325 is long(8 byte). So go for long value. U can get it in that way

```
Date myDate = new Date(); // current time    
myDate.getTime();         // converts it to specified format.
```